# Elixir: is_function

Tags: elixir

I want to test some built-in function with `is_function`, but it fails:

```elixir
> add = fn a, b -> a + b end
#Function<12.118419387/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

> is_function add
true

> is_function is_function    # test itself
warning: variable "is_function" does not exist and is being expanded to "is_function()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  iex:27
```

How to test built-in function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Kernel.function_exported?/3` and pass it the module name, function name, and arity to check:

```
iex(1)> function_exported?(Kernel, :is_function, 1)
true
iex(2)> function_exported?(Kernel, :is_function, 2)
true
iex(3)> function_exported?(Kernel, :is_function, 3)
false
iex(4)> function_exported?(Kernel, :function_exported?, 3)
true
```

(All functions that are callable in Elixir without importing any module, e.g. `is_function` or `+` are defined in the `Kernel` module.)

Comment: Ok that is the solution, but for a total noobie, what is the reason that `is_function is_function` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Apart to what @Dogbert said you also can use `is_function(&is_function/1)` to check if there is available such function in scope. Such syntax is required due to no difference between function name and variable name in Elixir.

Comment: One additional wrinkle to think about--in the original poster's example add is a _variable_ which contains a lambda.  is_function is a named function.  I mean to say that while is_function(&is_function/1) will work, is_function(&add/0) will not. Neither will is_function(&add/2).  Just for sake of completeness.

Comment: This will never return false. `is_function(&A.b/1) #=> true` even though the module `A` doesn't exist.

Comment: And for local functions this will be a compile time error if the function doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems that `is_function()` is useless.

Comment: Not exactly, because you still can use it as a guard and then it can provide some value.